# Cannot connect to TFS in VS2013 anymore

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

Over the last few days, I have had a LOT of trouble trying to get VS2013 Ultimate on my PC to connect to my TFS servers...

I will give you a quick rundown on what is happening... I did an update to VS2013 (on my PC only) to 'Update 4' a few days back and that seems to be when the problem started... 
At first when I would try and 'connect to team foundation server' I was getting an error (and yeah typical end user, I didnt note what it was), I just assumed that there was a problem with that server, because we have had a few issues with it.. it wasnt until I tried to connect to a different server, that I got the same error.  Thats when I realised it wasnt the server that was the problem.

I have done a bit of investigating... I can open VS2010 and connect to both servers no problems at all...
I can open VS2013 and VS2013 on my laptop (which I havent updated yet), and I can connect to both server no worries... so it is definitely NOT the TFS servers...

I found a few threads on here that all said to clear out the cache files in Team Foundation version 5.0 (and I also did 3.0 because it was there), no difference.
I went back into 'connect to team foundation server' and actually removed both of the servers from the list, in the hopes that adding them back in would fix the issue... but no... it now gives me the following error:

TS31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server: http://xxxxxxxx:8080/tfs.  Team foundation server Url: http://xxxxxxxxxx:8080/tfs.

> Possible reasons for this failure include:
>
> - The name, port number or protocol for the TFS is incorrect. (have checked and they are all correct)
> - The TFS is offline (definitely not... )
> - The password has expired or incorrect (I dont even get that far down the track to enter the password)

I decided that I would do a system restore, back to when I installed the update... did that, except for some reason I can only back 4 days, and the update was done prior to that.. 
I went into control panel and uninstalled the updates... made no difference
I ended up uninstalling VS2103 completely, restarted PC, reinstalled VS2013... went to connect to TFS... same problem...

I really have no idea at all how to fix this... can anyone at all help???

Comment: Does tfs web access work from that machine?

Comment: Hi @MikeCheel, yes I can connect to tfs webportal from this machine

Comment: And you peeped this article? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244143.aspx

Comment: Yeah I went through that article, and a few more similar ones.. I can't find anything that suggests what is going on... one thing I have just noticed though, when I open VS, and go to File > Account Settings > Sign in... I get a 'Sorry, we ran into a problem... The online service is not available. Please try again later...

Comment: Can you sign in to hotmail \ live with the same id?

Comment: What TFS server version are you connecting to?

Comment: Which version of TFS? Is there a proxy server involved? Is there a username stored in the Windows Credential manager? What version of Windows are you using? Have you tried uninstalling VS2013 using the `vs_setup /uninstall /force` option and installing it from a Visual Studio 2013 with update 5 ISO?